# How should I delete a firebase storage file?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

After attempting to delete a file I get the notification that it was successful. However, when I check the storage console page the document is still there.

If I manually specify the name of a file that was previously uploaded then that one will be deleted successfully.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Is it somehow related to the fact that I just uploaded the file and now I'm deleting it? Is there some kind of cache on the storage ref that I have to query again in order for it to know that the new file exists?

I am following the documentation provided by Google here.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/delete-files

Here is my code

```
            const storage = firebase.storage();
            const picture = storage.ref().child('images/' + file.name);
              picture
                .delete()
                .then(function () {
                  notification.success({
                    message: 'File Deleted',
                    placement: 'bottomLeft',
                  });
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                  console.error(error);
                  notification.warning({
                    message: 'There was an error',
                    placement: 'bottomLeft',
                  });
                });
```

### Update

When I say, "manually specifying the file" I mean that I can do this

```
const picture = storage.ref().child('images/alreadyUploadedImage.png');
```

Then run the same code to delete. This is why I asked about caching since it seems that if I reload my browser session by changing this text in my code that I can now delete a file. Also, this doesn't work for the file I just uploaded (before I refresh my browser). If I change the name in the code to, 'images/image.png' and then upload an image with that name and then immediately try to delete it, it doesn't work. But if I then refresh the browser and add another image, then delete that one, the 'image.png' file is gone from storage.

Here is a gif showing the file and firebase storage after the delete is complete on the client.
[image]

Comment: Do you have object versioning enabled?  Perhaps it's successfully deleted but you see a previous version?  If that's not it, can you elaborate on the _manually specifying the file_ comment?

Comment: You can check whether object versioning is enabled https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#check

Comment: Did you refresh the console page to see if the file was actually gone?  The console doesn't show updates in real time like it does for Firestore and Realtime Database.

Comment: @Noel object versioning is suspended on this bucket and it has never been turned on.

Comment: @DougStevenson I do a refresh of that page every time and the file is still there.

Comment: @Noel I updated my question to include some clarification regarding, "manually specifying the file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was calling the put method again after I was calling the delete method. I'm using AntD and the Upload component, which has getValueFromEvent={normFile}. This, "normFile" function gets called every time a file is uploaded or removed. So I just had to return from that function if the event was, event.status === 'removed'.